# android scrollview vertical scrollbar not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

So I have below layout for **custom AlertDialog**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popuplayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="DateTime"
        android:textColor="#cccccc"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#333333" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/popup_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/popup_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Message Text"
            android:textColor="#FFCC00"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSpam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="markSpam"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Mark as Spam" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is how I am showing it:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(
    R.layout.activity_show_notification, null);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
    context);

alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

// create an alert dialog
AlertDialog popup = alertDialogBuilder.create();

popup.setTitle(title);
popup.setMessage("");
popup.show();

TextView messageText = (TextView) popup.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageText.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
messageText.setHeight(0);
messageText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

TextView popupDate = (TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.popup_date);
TextView popupText = (TextView) popup.findViewById(R.id.popup_text);
popupDate.setText(mdate);
popupText.setText(message);

popupText.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

However when there is longer text, it is cut and vertical scrollbar doesn't show up :(

Can anyone help what I am missing here ? Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

### Update

Here is activity in app xml file using holo theme for the dialog:

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.domain.notifier.ShowNotification"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_show_notification"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
 </activity>
```

And styles.xml file:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.


        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

This is how I start alert dialog activity:

```
Intent intnt = new Intent(context, ShowNotification.class);
intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
intnt.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

intnt.putExtra("address", address);
intnt.putExtra("body", body);
intnt.putExtra("date", date);
context.startActivity(intnt);
```

Comment: hi dev01 , why u don't use from <ScrollView>  in your xml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your issue and it works after some modifications. Basically I made the view lookup from the promptView.

```
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.test, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);

    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

    // create an alert dialog
    AlertDialog popup = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    popup.setTitle("title");

    TextView messageText = (TextView) promptView.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    TextView popupDate = (TextView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.popup_date);
    TextView popupText = (TextView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.popup_text);

    popupDate.setText("date");
    popupText.setText(longTestString);


    popup.show();
```

UPDATE:

I've overlooked that in my solution the scrollview pushes out the button on the bottom.
It works fine if you add a layout-weight in your Scrollview. It than takes all available space and displays the bars if necessary.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/popuplayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popup_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="DateTime"
    android:textColor="#cccccc"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#333333" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/popup_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/popup_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Message Text"
        android:textColor="#FFCC00"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSpam"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="markSpam"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Mark as Spam" />
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what changes have you done ? Can you please elaborate a little more, I just see almost same thing

Comment: Now getting `android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`. Do i need to make some change to code as well other than layout ?

Comment: YEs i am already using layout weight but getting error i mentioned above :(

Comment: Fixed that error but it still doesn't show scrollbar

Comment: Attached a screenshot. Works in my case. Since we have the layout and same code its maybe a global style you have set on your scrollviews? Like `android:scrollbars="none"`?

Comment: This was the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23382360/android-sms-broadcast-receiver-not-getting-full-text-for-larger-sms solved :) and sorry my bad