# Scroll view for custom dialog

Tags: android

I have been trying to add scrollview for custom dialog box but it doesn't scroll. I tried all the suggested answers on this website but couldn't succeed. I have posted my layout.xml file here. Please help me out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/New_Cust_Popup_Background"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:ignore="ScrollViewSize,InefficientWeight,RtlHardcoded,UselessParent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/pop_element"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="373dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blackframe_edttxt"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true" >

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/AutoCmpltTxtViewCountry"
            style="@style/Custom_newCust_popup_edit_style"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/AutoCmpltTxtViewState"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/new_cust_popup_Country" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EdtAddress"
            style="@style/Custom_newCust_popup_edit_style"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/new_cust_popup_Address"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/AutoCmpltTxtViewCity"
            style="@style/Custom_newCust_popup_edit_style"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/EdtAddress"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/new_cust_popup_City" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/AutoCmpltTxtViewState"
            style="@style/Custom_newCust_popup_edit_style"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/AutoCmpltTxtViewCity"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/new_cust_popup_State" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EdtPostalCode"
            style="@style/Custom_newCust_popup_edit_style"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/AutoCmpltTxtViewCountry"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:hint="@string/new_cust_popup_Postal_Code"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnClosePopup"
            style="@style/Custom_newCust_popup_button_style"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/BtnPopUpSave"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/EdtPostalCode"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/BtnPopUpSave"
            android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
            android:text="@string/new_cust_popup_Cancel"
            tools:ignore="ButtonOrder,HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BtnPopUpSave"
            style="@style/Custom_newCust_popup_button_style"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/BtnClosePopup"
            android:text="@string/new_cust_popup_Save"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,RtlHardcoded" />

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: Post your layout.xml file.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23364163/android-scrollview-vertical-scrollbar-not-showing-up

Comment: please post the code where you instantiate that **custom dialog box** and how you deal with it.